# LMMS MIDI notes don't stop

Tags: midi, electronic-music

I don't know I'm right place but I connected my Casio ToneBank CT-670 to my DAW (LMMS 1.2.2) I can hear the notes I played but it does not stop. How can I set the DAW or the tonebank to sense my push and pull movements?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there is an issue with the note off signal. In midi you get a signal for the start of a certain pitch as well as a signal for the pitch to stop (although sometimes this also uses a start event with velocity 0).

You could write a little debugging application using the jack module in python to log the the events your midi keyboard sends.

Comment: If on Linux, qmidiroute has a small utility for logging midi events :)

Comment: The reason why some sources send a NOTE ON message with a velocity of 0 to stop a note, instead of a NOTE OFF message, is that it can take less data, and hence less time.  (Most MIDI messages normally have a status byte followed by two data bytes — but by using ‘running status’, the status byte can be omitted if the next message is of the same type.  So in a long stream of NOTE ON/OFF messages, it could give a one-third speed-up.)  — Of course, this relies on the receiver _knowing_ to treat 0-velocity NOTE ON messages as note offs…